# Exported Eclipse RCP application reading a local properties file

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I developing a plugin which reads from a .properties file for the database connection, but after exporting the plugin, the .properties file is wrapped up inside the jar'ed plugin and not able to be changed on the fly.

did some research, some suggested creating fragments or features to compliment the reading of the properties file on the fly and points to

http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_feature_generating_build.htm

tried using eclipse to creature fragments but am lost as in how to create a feature t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the properties file in the root of the target Eclipse installation (or the root of your RCP application). You can then access it using `Platform.getInstallLocation()`.

With regards to creating a feature, the Eclipse RCP tutorial "Creating a Rich Client Application" contains a section entitled "Define a feature-based product".

Comment: @jonleech How did you get on?